# How to get the order number of the current entry in a structure

Tags: entrymodel, order

Is there a way in Craft to get the order property of the current entry when it's in a structure? For example say you have the following structure:

- Parent Page

  - Child One
  - Child Two
  - Child Three

Is there a way to get what order property Child Two is in relation to its siblings so in this case it would be 1 (zero based)?

In my templates I am wanting to be able to grab the order property for the current entry by doing something like `{{ entry.getOrder() }}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a `positionedBefore` parameter for `craft.entries`. Use this with a criteria model filtered to
show the entries you are interested in only.

```
{% set parent = entry.getParent() %}
{% set siblingsIds = parent.getChildren().ids() %}

{% set positionedBefore = craft.entries({
    id: siblingsIds,
    order: 'lft desc',
    positionedBefore: entry,
}).total() %}
```

With the first two lines I'm getting the IDs of all of the entry's siblings. I then prepare a `craft.entries` criteria model using the siblings' IDs with the `id` parameter to query just for those entries, order them by `lft` in descending order (that's the db column Craft stores position info) and further filter with `positionedBefore` to get just the entries before `entry`.

Calling the `total` method returns the number of entries found.

Comment: Thank you @carlcs that seems to work perfect, could you just expand on your answer a little to help me understand exactly what its doing?

Comment: Very clever, I get it now. I didn't know about the `lft` column. Thank you again!