# How do I output the siblings position number?

Tags: structure

This question is related to this [thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17707/display-childrens-order-numbers).

```
{% for sibling in entry.getSiblings() %}  
{{ sibling.title }} {{ sibling.orderNumber }}
{% endfor %}
```

I thought you could pick this out of the ElementCriteriaModel, but that doesn't seem to be possible/available. Twig's for loop won't work either.

The result I am looking for is to echo the order number of the siblings in a **structure**.

```
Parent
Child order number 1
Child order number 2
Child order number 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon the answer I posted to this question [How to get the order number of the current entry in a structure](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13214/how-to-get-the-order-number-of-the-current-entry-in-a-structure), you should be able to get the order number in your for-loop like so:

```
{% set parent = entry.getParent() %}
{% set childrenIds = parent.getChildren().ids() %}

{% for sibling in entry.getSiblings() %}
    {% set orderNumber = craft.entries({
        id: siblingsIds,
        order: 'lft desc',
        positionedBefore: sibling,
    }).total() + 1 %}

    {{ sibling.title }} ({{ orderNumber }})
{% endfor %}
```